# Block current thread RXJS

Tags: multithreading, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, rxjs5

I have method which return Observable, like this:

```
public getCpuUsage(): Observable<string>  {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<string>) => {
        let plugin = new Plugin();
        plugin.open();
        plugin.OnEvent = (info: string, ack: string, nak: string) => {
            console.log("CPU [" + info + "].param1[" + ack + "].param2[" + nak + " ]");
            observer.next(info);
            plugin.close();
            observer.complete();
        };
        plugin.executeCommand('getCPUUsage');
    });
}
```

Object plugin has callback when will deliver info about cpu. It's work fine.

Other class can call this method like:

```
public executeInfo(): string {
    this.getCpuUsage()
        .subscribe({
            next: (infoAboutCpu) => {
                console.log(" Result: " + infoAboutCpu);
                return infoAboutCpu;
            }
        });

    console.log('Call this line');
    return '-1';
}
```

In log a see:
first log: 'Call this line'
second log(after 1-2 seconds, because callback called): 'Result: ${value_cpu_info}'

How I can block current thread, until get result from Observable ? Method executeInfo() must return correct value.

Comment: You can't. That's the whole point of Observables: represent the results of an **asynchronous** operation. executeInfo() can only return an Observable (or a Promise).

Comment: Don't try to block the current thread - javascript has only one thread and the whole app will stuck. Make executeInfo() return an observable as JB Nizet suggest in the above comment.

Comment: There are several issues here. For one `next:` does not propagate a return value from its callback. Also, while observables can work, this _really_ feels like it should be a Promise. As everyone has already said, it would be very undesirable to block JavaScript's sole thread. Perhaps you must in your actual code, but you need not block in order to cover the use case shown in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Block current thread RXJS

There is only 1 thread in JavaScript. You can block it with

```
while(true) {
 // insert break logic here
}
```

But I highly recommend you reconsider the requirement.

Comment: Don't try to block the current thread - javascript has only one thread and the whole app will stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my application logic.